# Save value of input in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to save the value of user input into the local storage, which will I hope to stay even after the page refreshes or I close the browser completely. How do I do this?

```js
allNames = []

function submit() {
  var names = document.getElementById("names").value;
  allNames.push(names);
  localStorage.setItem("names", names)
}

document.getElementById("namesList").innerHTML = allNames
```

```html
<input id="names" placeholder="Enter Your Party's names">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<div id="namesList"></div>
```

I would like for the total names to be saved and displayed into the  tag even after the page refreshes. How do I do this?

Comment: I've added an answer, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), it persists after browser reload.

Set data:

```
localStorage.setItem('test', 'value');
```

Get data:

```
localStorage.getItem('test');
```

Remove data:

```
localStorage.removeItem('test');
```

First, you need to load the data to `namesList` from `localStorage`, then on submit just push to the previously saved data, and save it again, load the new data.

Also, in order to work as expected, you need to use `JSON.stringify` before saving it to the `localStorage`, and `JSON.parse` after you get the data.

With your code, [working example on jsBin](https://jsbin.com/zabomakojo/edit?html,js,output):

```js
function submit() {
  var names = document.getElementById("names").value;
  var allNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allNames")) || [];
  allNames.push(names);
  localStorage.setItem("allNames", JSON.stringify(allNames));
  document.getElementById("names").value = '';
  document.getElementById("namesList").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("allNames");
}

document.getElementById("namesList").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("allNames");
```

```html
<input id="names" placeholder="Enter Your Party's names">
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<div id="namesList"></div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this.

```js
allNames = localStorage.getItem("names");
if (allNames) allNames = allNames.split(';;;');
document.getElementById("namesList").innerHTML = allNames

function submit() {
  var partnerName = document.getElementById("names").value;
  allNames.push(names);
  localStorage.setItem("namesList", allNames.join(';;;'));
  document.getElementById("namesList").innerHTML = allNames;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
// Store data
var someData = 'The data that I want to store for later.';
localStorage.setItem('myDataKey', someData);

// Get data
var data = localStorage.getItem('myDataKey');

// Remove data
localStorage.removeItem('myDatakey');
```

DOC

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: I don't know the data that will be stored, I want to have the input be stored into the local storage rather than a pre-defined value.